# Weird behavior: GUI won't start, but terminal emacs will

Tags: init-file, terminal-emacs, start-up, gui-emacs, gui

As I said in the title, I'm having a problem with starting Emacs, whenever I try to start it with `rofi`, nothing happens, and when I try and start with terminal (using `emacs`), it returns ["Args out of range: 0, 100"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvXS9.png) without opening up Emacs. Whenever I use Emacs in terminal however (with `emacs -nw`), it starts just fine. This behavior continues even after I moved my `.emacs.d` directory to `.emacs.d.bak` and even after I uninstall and reinstall Emacs. Any ideas what is going on and how I can fix this?

Here is my configuration [myinit.org](https://pastebin.com/ZNwM22Se) [init.el](https://pastebin.com/hpAgMAbH)

edit:

OS: Arch Linux  Emacs version: 26.1

Comment: Please add your operating system and emacs version. What happens if you start `emacs -Q`?

Comment: `args-out-of-range` is a standard error. You can start emacs with `--debug-init` to find out what caused the error.

Comment: If I start it with "emacs -Q", it starts just fine, but starting with "emacs --debug-init" also returns `Args out of range: 0, 100`

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out! It turns out there was a problem in my `~/.Xresources` file preventing it from loading.