# Gui won't start, throws an "Args out of range: 0, 100"

Tags: frames, debugging

The only response I got is this:
[Weird behavior: GUI won't start, but terminal emacs will](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46201/weird-behavior-gui-wont-start-but-terminal-emacs-will/46207#46207?newreg=c86b25e726b44c26a96f643ab376fc9b)

But he doesn't clarify on the solution. I have the same problem, my .Xdefaults and/or .Xresources causes the error

This is my .Xresources

```
*.color0: #1d2021
*.color1: #cc241d
*.color2: #98971a
*.color3: #d79921
*.color4: #458588
*.color5: #b16286
*.color6: #689d6a
*.color7: #a89984
*.color8: #928374
*.color9: #fb4934
*.color10: #b8bb26
*.color11: #fabd2f
*.color12: #83a598
*.color13: #d3869b
*.color14: #8ec07c
*.color15: #ebdbb2
!! Transparency (0-255):
*.alpha: 230
```

If I remove .Xresources emacs starts with no issue at all, but that meeses up with my i3blocks and i3 config

Comment: Did you follow the advice about using `--debug-init`?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently Emacs expects the value of `alpha` to be within [0, 100], as I can reproduce this issue with `alpha` set to a value outside of that exact range.

Poking around in its codebase, you can find the `x_set_alpha` function in `src/frame.c` signaling an "Args out of range" error on the same condition.

As an immediate fix you can specify an Emacs-specific `alpha` resource setting to be within that range

```
Emacs.alpha: 90
```

or alternatively add `(setq inhibit-x-resources t)` to your init file to prevent Emacs from loading X resources.

Moreover I'm not sure if this would be regarded as an actual bug upstream. Any application taking an X resource as input is free in the interpretation of its value. Adding custom settings per nonconforming application should be sufficient.

The sudden exit on an unexpected out-of-range value in the given X resources could definitely be regarded as a UX bug, though.